# Append a static value using <s: iterator> tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, netbeans-7

I need to append a ":00" value with the below code output in my jsp page.

```
<s:iterator begin="0" end="23" status="stat">
   <option ><s:property value="%{#stat.index}" ></s:property></option>
</s:iterator>
```

the above code gives 0,1,2,... upto 23, but i need the output as 
0:00
1:00
2:00... etc.

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:iterator begin="0" end="23" status="stat">
   <option ><s:property value="%{#stat.index}" ></s:property>:00</option>
</s:iterator>
```

I simply added ":00" string in front of the `s:property` tag.

Comment: can u also comment for the "if else" condition check in s iterator

Comment: You can go to [link](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-if-elseif-else-tag-example/). He shows examples using `<s:if/>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<option> <s:property value="%{#stat.index}"/> :00</option>
```

for your purpose.

So why you want check condition here?